# Asynchronous JS Request: setrequestheader authorization

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I am trying to make an Asynchronous XMLHttpRequest to unsplash.com to grab a picture. I did a dev account and i was provided with:

1. Authorization code
2. Application ID
3. Secret

I put the Authorization code in setRequestHeader() but i am getting a 401 error

"{"errors":["OAuth error: The access token is invalid"]}"

```
 imgRequest.open('GET', `https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos?page=1&query=${searchedForText}`);
imgRequest.setRequestHeader('Authorization','Authorization code');
imgRequest.send();
```

Comment: in that case the access token (not shown in your code is it?) is invalid - I guess that's what the error is telling you

Comment: As mentioned in my comment for 31piy i tested the `CLIENT-ID` directly inside the url, it responded with a JSON normally. so the problem isn't with the `CLIENT-ID`

Comment: My time machine is out of action, so, I apologise for not reading a comment made 1 hour after my comment was posted :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://unsplash.com/documentation#public-actions), the API requires the token, preceded with string **Client-ID** in the header.

So you need to pass the value in the header as `Client-ID YOUR_APPLICATION_ID` instead of just passing the token. Alternatively, you can also pass the token in the query parameters like this:

```
https://api.unsplash.com/photos/?client_id=YOUR_APPLICATION_ID
```

The above is specifically for the public actions, such as grabbing a photo. For private actions, you need to do a complex task, which is out of scope of this question.

Comment: when i am using the client ID inside the url, the API is responding with a JSON.

But when i am using `Client-ID MY_CLIENT_ID` inside `setRequestHeader`, it is responding with the OAuth Error message. I am only using the request for search and download which are public

Comment: @YMA981 -- Then I guess there is something wrong at the API end. You can talk to their support for more help, and meanwhile, you can use the query param format.

Comment: You are right again, out of the blue, the site responded after i used the `setRequestHeader`